# C, Linker: How to use weak symbols with static library

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have a large code base which is mainly built as binary. I have changed the Makefile to create a static library and I am creating a binary linking the library.

When I use it as a static library, code doesn't run due to weak symbols undefined reference.

```
gcc test.c -L . -lasntc -ltc -lresolv -lnetlink -lutil -ltc -lm -o mytc
 nm mytc | grep htb_qdisc_util
                 w htb_qdisc_util
```

I untared the archives which resulted in .o's and then using those object files, I created a binary and this however works as shown

`gcc   tc.o tc_qdisc.o tc_class.o tc_filter.o tc_util.o tc_monitor.o
 m_police.o m_estimator.o m_action.o m_ematch.o emp_ematch.yacc.o 
emp_ematch.lex.o asn_tc.o asn_global.o q_fifo.o q_sfq.o q_red.o q_prio.o q_tbf.o` 
`q_cbq.o q_rr.o q_multiq.o q_netem.o f_rsvp.o f_u32.o f_route.o f_fw.o f_basic.o` 
`f_flow.o f_cgroup.o q_dsmark.o q_gred.o f_tcindex.o q_ingress.o q_hfsc.o q_htb.o` 
`q_drr.o q_qfq.o m_gact.o m_mirred.o m_nat.o m_pedit.o m_skbedit.o p_ip.o`
`p_icmp.o p_tcp.o p_udp.o em_nbyte.o em_cmp.o em_u32.o em_meta.o q_mqprio.o` `static-syms.o tc_core.o tc_red.o tc_cbq.o tc_estimator.o tc_stab.o  -lresolv -L.` `-lnetlink -lutil -L. -lm -o tc`

```
 nm tc | grep htb_qdisc_util
0000000000641bc0 D htb_qdisc_util
```

Just looking at the object files symbol table, following is seen

```
nm *.o | grep htb_qdisc_util
0000000000000000 D htb_qdisc_util
                 w htb_qdisc_util
```

Weak symbols resulting due to

```
extern char hfsc_qdisc_util[] __attribute__((weak)); if (!strcmp(sym, "hfsc_qdisc_util")) return hfsc_qdisc_util;
extern char htb_qdisc_util[] __attribute__((weak)); if (!strcmp(sym, "htb_qdisc_util")) return htb_qdisc_util;
```

How do I create a static library and what is happening when I create a binary